# Display two values in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi have a database with several values in one table but when i try to display the values there is nothing displayed.
The connection to the database is OK but the code does not display any values.

The table name is`beraknings_varden` and the values i want to display on the screen is `stigning` and `diameter`.

Here is the code that should display the values

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM beraknings_varden") or die(mysqli-error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result)){ 
   echo $row[stigning].", ";
   echo $row[diameter];
   echo "<br />";
}

mysqli_close($opendb);

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` requires a connection parameter.

Comment: where is your database connection code .. ? could you please post that too

Comment: please add a mysql tag to get a broader attention to your question

Comment: Please, post the result of `print_r($row)` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in your code:

- You need to add connection link identifier in `mysqli_query` function.
- Don't know what is this `mysqli-error()` this should be `mysqli_error()`.

**Modified code**:

```
$result = mysqli_query($opendb ,"SELECT * FROM beraknings_varden") or die(mysqli_error($opendb)); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo $row['stigning'].", "; 
    echo $row['diameter']; echo "<br />"; 
} 
mysqli_close($opendb);
```

**Side note**:

You must need to read this manual **([mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php))**.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, first you have to more careful when doing some database query.

You miss to give the connection `mysqli_query($opendb, "your Qry")` where its mandatory.

Skip over spaces when use the function of mysql. Look at there, `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`, what you write `mysqli_fetch_array ( $result)`.

**Your new Query:** Try this, may be its helpful.

```
<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($opendb, "SELECT `stigning`, `diameter` FROM beraknings_varden");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
       echo $row['stigning'].", ";
       echo $row['diameter'];
       echo "<br />";
    }
    mysqli_close($opendb);
?>
```

Simply this is also Okey,

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

But you may use some specification.

```
// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

you can also free the resource.

```
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing qutation inside the square brackets.

```
echo $row['stigning'].", ";

echo $row['diameter'];
```

Comment: if that was the problem, he'd see E_NOTICE errors making the cause obvious -  Notice: Use of undefined constant stigning

Comment: @hanshenrik agreed with u

Comment: This is unbelivable. Nothing works. Mybe its some problem from my internet provider ONE.COM. Or maybe its Windows 10 ?. Or my virusprogram? It could be a number of things. Anybody having a clue